# Smartsheet API 2.0 - Error - Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: < path

Tags: c#, api, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2

"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0...."

I keep getting the error from the code below.

```
 Sheet _TempSheet =  _SmartsheetClient.SheetResources.GetSheet((long)_SheetID, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

                        List<long> RowsToDeleteIDs = new List<long>(); 

                        foreach (Row _Row in _TempSheet.Rows)
                        {
                            RowsToDeleteIDs.Add((long)_Row.Id);
                            Console.WriteLine("Row: " + _Row.Id);
                        }

                        _SmartsheetClient.SheetResources.RowResources.DeleteRows((long)_SheetID, RowsToDeleteIDs, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I notice that you've tagged your question **smartsheet-c#-sdk-v1** -- I haven't tested with the Smartsheet C# SDK **v1**, but the following code snippet (which includes a straight copy/paste of your code snippet, after setting up the connection and setting the Sheet ID) works fine with [Smartsheet C# SDK **v2**](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-csharp-sdk).  Perhaps try using the **v2** SDK instead, and see if that resolves your issue?

```
// Setup connection
Token token = new Token();
token.AccessToken = "MY_TOKEN_VALUE";
SmartsheetClient _SmartsheetClient = new SmartsheetBuilder().SetAccessToken(token.AccessToken).Build();

// Set Sheet ID
long _SheetID = MY_SHEET_ID;

Sheet _TempSheet = _SmartsheetClient.SheetResources.GetSheet((long)_SheetID, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

List<long> RowsToDeleteIDs = new List<long>();

foreach (Row _Row in _TempSheet.Rows)
{
    RowsToDeleteIDs.Add((long)_Row.Id);
    Console.WriteLine("Row: " + _Row.Id);
}

_SmartsheetClient.SheetResources.RowResources.DeleteRows((long)_SheetID, RowsToDeleteIDs, true);
```

***Note***: In the code above, replace MY_TOKEN_VALUE with the value of your access token, and replace MY_SHEET_ID with the value of your Sheet ID.

Comment: Sorry I am using smartsheet-SDK.v2.
I am already doing the above but still get an error. all the other API methods are working as expected but that one in particular seems to throw an exception. My Token is set and the smartsheetclient is an instance of the smartsheetbuiler.

Comment: Have you stepped through in debug mode to identify which line specifically is generating that exception?  Have you tried copying/pasting my code exactly, replacing MY_TOKEN_VALUE with the value of your access token, replacing MY_SHEET_ID with the value of your Sheet ID, and running it?  Are you running version 2.0.0 of the SDK or version 2.0.1?  And finally, any chance that you downloaded the source of the SDK from Github and modified it in some way?